# Anchor Link Not Scrolling Down

Tags: html, hyperlink, magento2

I'm having a little trouble with an image linked to a section of the page.  This link works fine when input into the bar and loaded, it'll scroll down but once the base page is loaded, if i click the image with the link, it doesn't want to go down the page to the tabbed section in question.

https://www.bollostore.com/beolab-50

That is the base page i'm running it on whilst

https://www.bollostore.com/beolab-50#product.view.paybyfinance is the link to the 'pay by finance' tab lower down the page.  It is this that works a-ok if i put it straight into the url bar.  But when I click the finance banner in the short description, it doesn't trigger.

The original that i've used is:

```html
<a href="https://www.bollostore.com/beolab-50#product.view.paybyfinance"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-1176 size-full" src="https://www.bollostore.com/media/tmp/catalog/product/c/l/click-to-calculate.jpg" alt="finance for your tv and audio" width="1000" height="auto" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put a name tag in a element like

```html
<a class="data switch" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="switch" href="#product.view.paybyfinance" name="product.view.paybyfinance" id="tab-label-product.view.paybyfinance-title">
                                    Pay by Finance                                </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joe.  I've applied that on page, i see that when clicked if that tab (pay by finance) is already open, it'll scroll down, but not if it's on the default 1st tab (more information)

Comment: mhh right the tabs is actually controlled by javascript  so i guess it makes sense to scroll it instead with javascript or jquery..

Comment: are you using jQeury in the website? i might be able to give you a code to scroll to top considering the offset.